# Why is kinetic energy only "often $(1/2)mv^2$"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, energy

I am reading the first few pages of Nakahara and refreshing my memory on physics I learned a while ago as a physics math undergrad. Nakahara defines a field $F$ to be conservative if it's the gradient of some potential $V(x)$. (standard)  Then he defines the total energy as $(1/2)mv^2+V(x)$. He then states that $E$ is "often" the kinetic+potential energy, hence deserving the name "total energy." I was taught that kinetic is defined as $(1/2)mv^2$. So what does he mean here?

**Addum:** The exact quote of Ref. 1 is:

> *The function $E$, which is often the sum of the kinetic energy and the potential energy, is called the **energy**.*

References:

1. M. Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology & Physics,* 2nd edition, 2003, Section 1.1.1.

Comment: Because the correct free value is $(\gamma - 1)mc^2$ (from relativity). In the limit of $v \ll c$ this is well approximated by the Newtonian form.

Comment: but the chapter is talking about classical mechanics there I think.  Not to mention that if we're speaking relativistically, then the kinetic energy is then never exactly equal to $1/2mv^2$ except when $v=0$.  Are you saying that in classical, it is true by definition that $1/2mv^2$ is the kinetic energy?

Comment: It's almost a matter of definition. You can define work and energy arbitrarily, so that $work = \kappa \int_\Gamma \vec{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$, which, through Newton's second law, works out to $1/2 \kappa m v^2$ when that force works on an otherwise free body, where $\kappa$ defines your work units. But, as @dmkee says, relativity and the resultant mass-energy equivalence means your unit system must also think of work on a free body begetting increased inertia, so your units will become very complicated and tangled unless you set $\kappa = 1$. Relativity unifies phenomena such that ....

Comment: ... clean unit definitions become more restricted: it really doesn't make much sense to define otherwise. There is a former question with some excellent answers that is almost an exact copy of yours, but I can't find it at the moment. Ron Maimon gave @dmckee 's answer: you could try going through all of Ron's answers if you're really keen but he is / was prolific, so that is a formidable search in itself.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal is probably referring to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27847

Comment: You haven't defined what is 'E'. Please state the question properly and provide the exact quote from the text.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11905/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I don't understand what your proint is. He says the total energy has a component called the kinetic energy $1/2mv^2$, so how why is this a problem with your definition of kinetic energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition for point particles is:

$T = \frac{p^2}{2m}$, where $T$ denotes my kinetic energy.

1. If you are dealing with **classical physics**, the momentum for a point-particle equals $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}$, which would give you $T = \frac{mv^2}{2}$.
2. In the theory of **special relativity** we notice that objects become heavier when they move, the momentum becomes: $\vec{p} = {m\vec{v}\gamma}$, where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$. Hence the kinetic energy becomes:
   $T={mc^2\gamma}$, this is derived below.
3. If you try to make a non-relativistic **electromagnetic Lagrangian**, it's not possible to incorporate the magnetic field in terms of a potential energy. So the solution is to define the momentum equal to $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}-\frac{q\vec{A}}{c}$, where A is the vector potential so that $\vec{B} = \nabla\times\vec{A}$. This would give an kinetic energy (or kinetic term in your Hamiltonian) equal to: $T = \frac{(m\vec{v}-\frac{q\vec{A}}{c})^2}{2m}$.
   One often calls $m\vec{v}$ the kinematic momentum and $\vec{p}$ the canonical momentum (since this is the momentum that follows from a Lagrangian). It are the canonical momenta that are called "thé momenta".
4. And last but not least, in **quantum mechanics** you work on a different kind of mathematical structure (in Hilbert-space in stead of the classical phase-space). By equivalence with wave-theory the momentum is derived as $\hat{p} = \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, where we have an operator $\hat{p}$ which works on that Hilbertspace.

> Note: from dj_mummy
>
> Note that the given relations for kinetic energy all assume the particle was originally at rest at a given time $t=t_0$. The kinetic energy is derived by using the work-energy theorem (difference in kinetic energy = work done on the point particle). Using the laws of classical physics (Newton's second law) we get:
>
> $T = \int\limits_{x_0}^{x_1}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x} = \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_1}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}\,dt = \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_1}\left(m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\right)\cdot \vec{v}\,dt= m\int\limits_{t_0}^{t_1} \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{v} = \frac{m}{2}v^2$. Where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity at time $t_1$.
>
> This gives us the kinetic energy in the case of classical physics! For the relativistic particle we define a 4-momentum $p^\alpha = m\frac{du^\alpha}{d\tau}$. Where $u^\alpha$ is the four-velocity and $\tau$ is the proper time. The derivation is actually done [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Relativistic_kinetic_energy_of_rigid_bodies) and we get the formula above !

Comment: Huh? Your factors of $\gamma$ in #2 are wrong. If you fix the gamma in the equation for p, the gamma in your equation for T is still wrong.

Comment: @BenCrowell It should be fixed by now ...

Comment: @Nick: But now it's not consistent with the assertion at the beginning that $T=p^2/2m$ in all cases, which I think is false.

Comment: @BenCrowell that's what I get for doing to many things at the same time, I god rid of the additive constant!

Comment: @Nick: Huh? I don't understand your most recent comment. There is no additive constant. The issue is that $T=p^2/2m$ is false in the relativistic case.