# Voltage and Energy in a capacitor

Tags: electricity, capacitance, voltage

Well, my first question is related to the energy of the capacitor. Why does the energy of capacitor equals $E=\frac{1}{2}QV$ and not $E=QV$;in other words, why we multiplied it by $\frac{1}{2}$??
My second question is why the sum of the voltage of each of the capacitors connected in series equals to that of the battery??

Comment: Check out these links regarding the energy storage.  It involves the amount of work it takes to move one charge from one plate to another.
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng.html
 http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng2.html

Comment: If a battery is connected to a series of _any_ kind of two-terminal devices, why would you not expect the total voltage to equal the voltage of the battery?  A battery is a pretty good approximation of an _ideal voltage source_.  That is, a component whose voltage does not depend on _anything_.

Comment: @jameslarge A battery is rather well approximated by an ideal voltage source in series with a Ohmic resistor. (And the voltage depends notably on the current, falling to zero in the case of a short circuit, with a characteristic short circuit current). But in the static case the current is zero and therefore the "voltage of the battery" is measured.

Comment: @SebastianRiese, good point.  I was imagining that with capacitors in the loop, not much current would flow.  But all that is kind of irrelevant.  Harish Chandra Rajpoot gave the correct answer which is Kirchoff's Voltage Law:  The instantaneous sum of voltages around any closed loop _must_ be zero.

Comment: [This question has been asked before](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112404/).

Answer (score 1):

Notice, let the charge $Q$  be stored in the capacitor having capacitance $C$, at voltage $V$ is $$Q=CV$$ 
since the voltage $V$ varies as the charge $q$ varies on the plates varies, hence let $dq$ be the elementary change in the charge $q$ at voltage $V$ at any instant then  the elementary energy $dE$ is given as $$dE=Vdq$$ Now, integrating both sides, the total energy stored is given as $$\int_{0}^{E} dE=\int_{0}^{Q}Vdq$$$$E=\int_{0}^{Q}\frac{q}{C}dq=\frac{1}{C}\int_{0}^{Q}qdq$$ 
$$E=\frac{1}{C}\left(\frac{1}{2}q^2\right)_{0}^{Q}=\frac{1}{2C}Q^2=\frac{1}{2}QV$$ 
By Kirchoff's voltage law states that for every series connected circuit the total sum of individual voltage drops will be equal in value of supply voltage