# What is the proof for kinetic energy $= mv^2/2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

What is the proof for kinetic energy $= \dfrac{mv^2}{2}$?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27847/2451 and links therein.

Comment: And also? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27847/

Answer (score 2):

According to work energy theorem we know
Work done = change in kinectic energy so elementary work done=$$F×ds$$ where $ ds$ is the elementary displacement.Futher we know Force =$$m×a=m×dv/dt$$ Thus work done=$$ m×a×ds=m×dv/dt×ds=m×dv×ds/dt$$$$=m×v×dv   $$integrating within limits from 0 to v we get total work done $=\dfrac{mv^2}{2}.$

Comment: But the WET is derived by knowing that K.E. = $1/2 m v^2$. So using the WET to deduce that K.E. = $1/2 m v^2$ is a circular argument.

Answer (score 1):

Work done= mass × acceleration × displacement
$$=m\times a\times s$$

From physics principal, Relation of initial velocity$(u)$ & final velocity$(v)$

$$v^2 = u^2 + 2as $$
  where $a$= acceleration & $s$ = displacement

But initial velocity is zero.

so $$v^2 = 2\times a\times s$$

put value of acceleration $a=\dfrac{v^2}{2s}$ into Work done equation

$$=m\times\dfrac{v^2}{2\not s}\times \not s$$
$$W.D.=\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Comment: Your second equation $v^2=... $ is specific to constant acceleration.