# How to derive the equation $-G\frac{Mm}{r_1}+G\frac{Mm}{r_2}=\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2-\frac{1}{2}mv^2_2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

I was just wondering how the following equation is derived:$$-G\frac{Mm}{r_1}+G\frac{Mm}{r_2}=\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2-\frac{1}{2}mv^2_2~?$$

---

I already understand why the work $W$ done in moving an object with mass $m$ by a force exerted by a mass $M$ from point $r_1$ to $r_2$ is given by

$$\Delta U = -G\frac{Mm}{r_1}+G\frac{Mm}{r_2}$$

yet the couple of proofs I've seen for $W=-\Delta KE$ assume that the acceleration is constant. How could one prove the equation in its more general form?

Comment: What proof technique you've seen assumes constant acceleration? Energy conservation gives us the general case.

Comment: This nothing but a conserved energy balance. Acceleration doesn't come into it.

Comment: @J.G. some version of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345301/deriving-the-equation-for-kinetic-energy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're familiar with calculus & vectors, then it is relatively straightforward to generalize the work-energy theorem to include forces that vary in direction and magnitude.  Here's how:

Start with Newton's Second Law:
$$
m \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = \vec{F}
$$
Take the dot product of both sides with $\vec{v}$:
$$
m \vec{v} \cdot \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}
$$
Recognize that according to the chain rule, $\vec{v} \cdot (d\vec{v}/dt) = \frac{1}{2} d( \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v})/dt$:
$$
\frac{m}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \left( v^2 \right) = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}
$$
Bring $m/2$ inside the derivative:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{1}{2} m v^2 \right) = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}
$$
Integrate both sides of the equation from some initial time $t_i$ to some final time $t_f$:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2} m v^2 \right)_{t = t_f} - \left(\frac{1}{2} m v^2 \right)_{t = t_i} = \int_{t_i}^{t_f} (\vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}) dt
$$
Recognize that the integral on the right is the [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) of the force along the path taken, and that the left-hand side is the change in the kinetic energy:
$$
\Delta (KE) = \int_{\vec{r}_i}^{\vec{r}_f} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}
$$
where $\vec{r}_i$ and $\vec{r}_f$ are the object's initial and final position.  This last integral is the general definition for the work done on an object:
$$
W \equiv \int_{\vec{r}_i}^{\vec{r}_f} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}
$$
You can hopefully see that this works out to be the more-familiar $W = \vec{F} \cdot \Delta \vec{r}$ for the case where $\vec{F}$ is constant.

Comment: Wouldn't $\vec{v}\cdot \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=\sum v_i\frac{dv_i}{dt}=2\sum\frac{1}{2}v_i\frac{dv_i}{dt}=2\sum\frac{dv_i^2}{dt}=2\frac{d(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v})}{dt}$?

Comment: @Leo why would differentiating $x^2$ give you $x/2$?

Comment: @Leo:  $$\frac{d v_i^2}{dt} = 2 v_i \frac{dv_i}{dt},$$ so your third equality is wrong.  (This is one of those identities that's easiest to see by working from right to left, not from left to right.)

Comment: You are right. One last thing, how do you show both integrals are equal?

Comment: @Leo:  If you mean the time integral (over $t$) and the line integral (over $\vec{r}$), they're true because of the definition of a line integral.  See the section "Line integral of a vector field" on the Wikipedia page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side of your equation is the change in Kinetic Energy of the mass.

This can be found by doing a Work done = Force x Distance formula, with a variable force, by integrating Newtons Force law, like this

$$\int^{r_2}_{r_1}\frac{GM}{r^2}dr $$