# What does the $2g$ mean? $v_y^2=v_{0y}^2+2g(y-y_0)$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

In the relationship
$$v_y^2=v_{0y}^2+2g(y-y_0),$$
what does the $2g$ mean?

Why do we have gravity being multiplied by 2? Don't say you need to know calculus; I know that. I don't want to know how but why.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27847/2451

Comment: Why are you questioning the 2? Why aren't you questioning the $g$?  It's not always $g$.

Comment: Do you question the $\frac{1}{2}$ in $y=y_0+v_{0y}t+\frac{1}{2}a t^2 $?

Comment: Although you want to exclude a calculus explanation, I am going to give it to you anyway: $$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} = v\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{dv^2}{dy} = g$$ Now integrate for $v^2$ in the last equality.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you find it more intuitive in another form: $$\frac{1}{2}mv_y^2 = \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 + mg(y-y_0)$$ This is just a statement of conversion of energy, in this case kinetic and potential energies.

Answer (score 2):

This is a kinematic equation, so it only applies when the acceleration is constant. Under this scenario, the average velocity of a particle over some duration of time $\Delta t$ is

$$v_{\mathrm{avg}} = \frac{1}{2}(v_{f} + v_{o}),$$

where $v_{f}$ is the particle's velocity at the end of $\Delta t$ and $v_{o}$ is its velocity at the beginning of $\Delta t$. The "2" in the fraction is going to carry through the derivation of your equation.

The next step is to write

$$\Delta t = \frac{(v_{f} - v_{o})}{a},$$

and substitute for $v_{\mathrm{avg}}$ and $\Delta t$ in $\Delta x = v_{avg} \Delta t$. Just trade $y$ for $x$ and $g$ for $a$ and work through the algreba.