# Centripetal force and energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, centripetal-force

I have a question related to centripetal force. 
Say there is a pendulum, then 
\begin{align}
mg[h_{max} - h_{current}] = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2}\ell F_{cp} \, .
\end{align} 
Solving for centripetal force would lead to a factor of 2 on the left hand side. 
Is there a physical meaning for this factor?

Answer (score 1):

The factor 2 comes from the kinetic energy, so the physical meaning of that factor is the same as if you solve for $v^2$. The centripetal force does no work since the $F_{cp}$ vector is perpendicular to the direction of motion, so while $\ell F_{cp}$ has the dimension of energy, it has no meaning in terms of $F \cdot \Delta x$ work.

The $\frac{1}{2}$ in kinetic energy has its own story, see for example the answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27847/why-is-there-a-frac-1-2-in-frac-1-2-mv2). Ultimately, it's due to how energy is defined in special relativity, but there are also non-relativistic explanations.