# Why Lagrangian is $L=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and not $mv^2$ for a free particle in an intertial frame? Both are proportional to the square of velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, conventions

Landau writes the Lagrangian of a free particle in a second inertial frame as $$L(v'^{2})=L(v^2)+\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^2}2\textbf{v}\cdot{\epsilon},$$ and then it's written that the *Lagrangian is in this case proportional to the square of velocity , and we write it as:* $$L=\frac{1}{2}mv^2,$$ my question is: why not just  $L=mv^2$? The latter case is  proportional to the square of velocity as well.

Comment: Related: [Why is there a $\frac 1 2$ in $\frac 1 2 mv^2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27847/2451)

Comment: As pointed out in the answer to the question [why is there a $\tfrac{1}{2} in \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/68723/17198): Take *F=ma* and evaluate - both sides - the integral from position $s_0$ to position $s$ 
$$ \int_{s_0}^sF \ ds = \int_{s_0}^sma \ ds $$
The following is independent of $F=ma$: integration of *acceleration* with respect to position: 
$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2 $$
Hence:
$$ \int_{s_0}^s F ds = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2 $$

Comment: In Landau's Mechanics force has not been introuced yet, and thus, maybe, this answer does not fit with his logical approach

Answer (score 0):

Both would work. It is just a matter of convention. Notice that if $x_0$ is an extremum of the function $S(x)$, it is also an extremum of $\alpha \cdot S(x)$ for constant $\alpha \neq 0$.